# Removing IIS APPPOOL/MyPool from folder does not cancel file write permissions

Tags: asp.net, iis, file-permissions, iis-8

I have an ASP.NET 2.0 application under IIS 8.5 in Classic mode where a page needs to write uploaded files to a folder outside the root of the app. When I first tired this I got something like

```
Access to the path 'D:\events\uploads\myfile.txt' is denied.
```

In the Security tab of D:\events I added "IIS AppPool/MyAppPool" and activated the Write permission. Everything worked fine then - as it should.

However, after **removing the MyAppPool from D:\events again the same page was still able to write files under D:\events.** Scary. A few experiments showed that that the page can now write files everywhere except C:\ C:\Windows C:\Users and D:.

UPDATE: To check which user or group might give access to IIS/ASP.NET I have created a folder C:\TestIISAccess disabled permission inheritance and gradually removed users and groups. Well, there are none left now, I can not even look inside the folder as admin. But my .aspx upload page reports it can still write files there. I have stopped & restarted IIS after all users were removed, makes no difference.

Can some please explain this behaviour and tell me how to cancel the write permission?

Comment: Reset IIS and see what happens.

Comment: @lex-Ii: I have restarted IIS and even rebooted the entire server. Does not help. For all folders I have tested there is nothing to see in the Security settings which should IMO grant AppPoolIdentity any elevated rights. If IIS threads have any scary hidden global rights, then why did it complain in the first place?

Comment: without seeing your IIS configuration and NTFS ACL on the disk I don't think anyone can literally tell the cause. Either you teach yourself enough about both, or you raise a support case via http://support.microsoft.com